# How to know uploader of a video using youtube v3 API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I want to retrieve name of the user who has uploaded a video. I could retrieve information like length of a video, title, description using [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) but  the uploader of the video. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a query for a video like this: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=j4ovbmsp6p0&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

you get a result like that:

`{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"4FSIjSQU83ZJMYAO0IqRYMvZX98/2gSGwmuY674XAGNAXoSrDENmJPo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"4FSIjSQU83ZJMYAO0IqRYMvZX98/ai8sU-I-pLgfr5cd4lRv2KdntL4\"",
   "id": "j4ovbmsp6p0",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-07-11T11:41:11.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCF7OtvI5wVzb5Jl74nI3Mkg",
    "title": "Woohoo!! I daut it!! #idautit - Das Originale WhatsApp Video - #Idautit Idauit idaudit",
    "description": "Das Originale I daut it Video #idautit. Der Sommertrend, bekannt geworden durch das virale WhatsApp Video. #idautit",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j4ovbmsp6p0/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j4ovbmsp6p0/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j4ovbmsp6p0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j4ovbmsp6p0/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j4ovbmsp6p0/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Idautit Official",
    "categoryId": "22",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Woohoo!! I daut it!! #idautit - Das Originale WhatsApp Video - #Idautit Idauit idaudit",
     "description": "Das Originale I daut it Video #idautit. Der Sommertrend, bekannt geworden durch das virale WhatsApp Video. #idautit"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}`

The uploading user is always the channel itself. So you just need to take the properties "channelTitle" or "channelId" to make further lookups.

Here you can find some detailed information: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#channels

It says:

> Whereas the v2 API provided a way for retrieving a user's profile, the
>   v3 API provides a method for retrieving information about a channel.
>   There are several differences between the two implementations: [...]

Comment: Thank you very much but I was checking if I can get all this info just in one call for search. Any idea if it is possible in just one call?

Comment: I don't think so. I was looking for a way too, because i have to migrate from v2 to v3, but i have not found a way.